# Combine.perKey receives empty groups when a Repeatedly trigger is used

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm using `Combine.perKey` to combine multiple records into one in Dataflow. I'm finding that if I use the following window, my custom SerializableFunction sometimes receives an empty iterable.

```
p.apply(TextIO.Read.from(INPUT))
.apply(ParDo.of(new ParseRecords()))
.apply(Window.<Record>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(24)))
  .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
  .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
.discardingFiredPanes()
.apply(ParDo.of(new SetKey()))
.apply(Combine.<String, Record>perKey(new CombineRecords()))

// ...

static class CombineRecords implements SerializableFunction<Iterable<Record>, Record> {
  @Override
  public Record apply(Iterable<Record> records) {
    // sometimes, records has no items
    return Iterables.get(records, 0, null);
  }
}
```

If I remove `triggering`, then the function never receives an empty iterable.

My questions are:

- Is it expected that a SerializableFunction handling `Combine.perKey` would receive an empty iterable, with triggering in place?
- If so, with no records to combine, how can the SerializableFunction handle that? Returning `nil` or `false` does not seem to be an option.

I'm using Dataflow SDK 1.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the behavior you are seeing is that an "on time" pane may be emitted even if it is empty. You should either have a specific `Record` that can act as the identity (0 for addition, 1 for multiplication, etc) or allow the `Record` to be `null` and return that. Then the combining function would need to detect if any of the `records` are null and drop those.

This is partly described in [BEAM-210 (making this behavior configurable)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-210) and [BEAM-32 (making the default be only producing non-empty panes)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-32).